# Symfony2 - SonataAdmin - Empty admin_list block

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I have been trying to install SonataAdminBundle. I think I followed the documentation, plus I read some blogs about it. But I couldn't do it.

When going to the admin/dashboard page, i see the Sonata Title, i can see the sonata.block.service.text and the sonata.block.service.rss on the right, but there is nothing in the admin_list block => I can't see my Entity.

Here is how I set it up. I maybe forgot something ?
Here is the app/config/config.yml

```
imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }
- { resource: ../../src/Pierre/TennisBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml }

...

sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]

        sonata.block.service.text:
        sonata.block.service.rss:

sonata_doctrine_orm_admin:
    # default value is null, so doctrine uses the value defined in the configuration
    entity_manager: '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'

    templates:
        form:
            - SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle:Form:form_admin_fields.html.twig
        filter:
        - SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle:Form:filter_admin_fields.html.twig
        types:
            list:
                array:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_array.html.twig
                boolean:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_boolean.html.twig
                date:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_date.html.twig
                time:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_time.html.twig
                datetime:   SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_datetime.html.twig
                text:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                trans:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_trans.html.twig
                string:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                smallint:   SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                bigint:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                integer:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                decimal:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                identifier: SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig

            show:
                array:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_array.html.twig
                boolean:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_boolean.html.twig
                date:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_date.html.twig
                time:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_time.html.twig
                datetime:   SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_datetime.html.twig
                text:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
                trans:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_trans.html.twig
                string:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
                smallint:   SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
                bigint:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
                integer:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
                decimal:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig

sonata_admin:
    security:
        handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.role

    title:      Sonata Project
    title_logo: /bundles/sonataadmin/logo_title.png
    templates:
        # default global templates
        layout:  SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig
        ajax:    SonataAdminBundle::ajax_layout.html.twig
        dashboard: SonataAdminBundle:Core:dashboard.html.twig

        # default actions templates, should extend a global templates
        list:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list.html.twig
        show:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show.html.twig
        edit:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:edit.html.twig

    dashboard:
        blocks:
            # display a dashboard block
            - { position: left, type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list }

            # Customize this part to add new block configuration
            - { position: right, type: sonata.block.service.text, settings: { content: "<h2>Welcome to the Sonata Admin</h2> <p>This is a <code>sonata.block.service.text</code> from the Block Bundle, you can create and add new block in these area by configuring the <code>sonata_admin</code> section.</p> <br /> For instance, here a RSS feed parser (<code>sonata.block.service.rss</code>):"} }
            - { position: right, type: sonata.block.service.rss, settings: { title: Sonata Project's Feeds, url: http://sonata-project.org/blog/archive.rss }}

        groups:
            sonata_page:
                label: TestLabel
                items: ~



    # set to true to persist filter settings per admin module in the user's session
    persist_filters: true
```

My admin class

```
namespace Pierre\TennisBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;

use Pierre\TennisBundle\Entity\Tennismen;

class TennismenAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('name')
               ;
    }

    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper
            ->add('name')
               ;
    }

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('name')
                ;
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
namespace Pierre\TennisBundle\Controller;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController as Controller;

class TennismenAdminController extends Controller
{
}
```

And my service:

```
# TennisBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml
services:
    pierre.tennis.admin.tennismen:
        class: Pierre\TennisBundle\Admin\TennismenAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: sonata_page, label: Blog }
        arguments: [null, Pierre\TennisBundle\Entity\Tennismen, PierreTennisBundle:TennismenAdmin]
```

So I think i respected the guide... but I can't see my Entity Tennismen in the dashboard.

Answer (score 4):

But in some cases granting SUPER_ADMIN role to all users is not a solution, make sure you have this line in yout parameters.yml :

```
security.acl.permission.map.class: Sonata\AdminBundle\Security\Acl\Permission\AdminPermissionMap
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try `SonataAdminBundle:CRUD` as your third argument in the service definition? Also, ensure you have logged in with super admin (if you have SonataUserAdmin installed). Also, try removing `dashboard` part in your `config.yml` or try using as little configuration as possible all together.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your attention. I have tried both but it still doesn't show anything. I am not using SonataUser, but i have installed FOSuser. WOuld it be a ROLE thing ? do you know what Role should I have ?

Answer (score 0):

I Could solve it thanks to you !
I had to add the FOSUser SUPER_ADMIN role to my user to be able to see the admin_block.

Thanks!